# Sentiment analysis - flair pretrained model classifier. How to speed up

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I want to classify emotions with pretrained flair english model from flair library. I have about 90 000 tweets and I want to classify everything.

Problem is that flair library doing that in about 7 hours.
To compare NLP sentiment classifier or TextBlob can do this in 1 minute...

My code to that problem is:

```
def flair_sentiment(data, classifier):
"""
data : text sequence (pandas.Series)
classifier : pretrained flair classifier
"""
values = []
for Item in data:
    tokenized = Sentence(Item)
    classifier.predict(tokenized)
    values.append(tokenized.labels[0].score)
return values

df['sentiment'] = flair_sentiment(df.tweets, classifier)
```

Comment: You managed to speed up flair sentiment classifier somehow? I have the same issue. It's so slow....

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try the following steps:

1. In your code, the sentiment is predicted for one tweet at a time. You can speed it up using batch prediction.
2. Currently for Flair 0.6, there are two sentiment models: "sentiment" (BERT-based which is the default one) and "sentiment-fast" (RNN-based which is slightly less accurate). Their performances are reported at: https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_2_TAGGING.md#list-of-pre-trained-text-classification-models
3. Of course, using GPU will speed things up a lot.

Below is the code for analyzing sentiments from tweets using batch prediction. It also shows the running times for both sentiment models. You can see that the RNN-based model is much faster than the default one.

```py
from time import time

from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.models import TextClassifier


def flair_sentiment(texts, classifier):
    sentences = [Sentence(text) for text in texts]
    classifier.predict(sentences, mini_batch_size=32)
    return [
        (sent.labels[0].value, sent.labels[0].score)
        for sent in sentences
    ]


for sentiment_model_name in ("sentiment", "sentiment-fast"):
    classifier = TextClassifier.load(sentiment_model_name)

    start_time = time()
    tweets = 512 * [
        "For what a beautiful day. #elated",
        "It's broken"
    ]
    sentiments = flair_sentiment(tweets, classifier)
    # print(sentiments)
    print(f"* Sentiment model {sentiment_model_name}: running time = {time() - start_time:.2f} second(s)")
```

Output:

```
2020-09-22 11:50:14,027 loading file /Users/khuc/.flair/models/sentiment-en-mix-distillbert_3.1.pt
* Sentiment model sentiment: running time = 19.99 second(s)
2020-09-22 11:50:36,369 loading file /Users/khuc/.flair/models/sentiment-en-mix-ft-rnn.pt
* Sentiment model sentiment-fast: running time = 0.43 second(s)
```